# get the pixel count between two points in a bitmap

Tags: c#, .net

I am beginner in C#.NET .I am on a project to process approach maps.this map contains the surrounding area of a runway,where the flight can fly in order to land.
this map is a bitmap image.it contains longitudes and latitudes on the borders of the image!

now the aim of the project is to get the geological coordinates(lats/long) of points on the map,(when clicked or hovered on that point by mouse,) based on the given geological coordinates on the border of the map.so if we give the input for a point with its lats/long coordinates the other points on the map can be interpolated.

suppose there be X pixels between any two longitudes and Y pixels between any two latitudes.if we set a reference point ,then depending on the distance(number of pixels from the reference point in x and y direction individually) of the pixel that is being hovered or clicked by mouse pointer we can get the lats/longitudes of that point in a small window(may be like tool tip or pop up).

the math surrounding the interpolation can be:

new lat=  ref lat +  [ref lat(only minutes)/Y] *(vertical distance between reference point and new point in pixels)

new long=  ref long -  [ref long(only minutes)/X] *(horizontal distance between reference point and new point in pixels).

there is a point called mid point on the centre of the run way(at the centre of the graph).i also need to find the angle made by line joining midpoint and new point(where the mouse hovers or clicks) with the verticle of the map.

so any one please give me ideas how to start the project and what are things (tool bar controls,methods) i require to build the gui containing picture window and pop up window(containing information about that point or pixel) where ever i click the mouse .thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The question asked in the headline is answered as follows:

```
double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.Pow(y2 - y1, 2));
```

That's the distance between two points on a plane, and hence on a bitmap.

The question asked in the body isn't answered easily at all. If you have a given map, the function defining the distance between two coordinates may not be linear. Here's an article on [Map projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) that shows some of the different map types. To be able to calculate what you need, you first need to know what kind of map you're actually working on, and hence adjust your formulas accordingly.

If your map is only of small size, this may not make much of a difference. You were talking about a *runway* at one point, if this is just for one airport, then projection isn't necessarily an issue. If you're working out distances between two runways of different airports, that will be a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite specific to your needs and has a few elements that could be questions in their own right. You might want to break it down into several questions and or research each item independently. e.g.

You'll want to look into [WPF](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=learning%20wpf%20site%3astackoverflow.com&meta=) or [Windows Forms](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=learning%20windows%20forms%20site%3astackoverflow.com&meta=).

You'll need to learn how to [calculate the angle between two points](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=calculate%20the%20angle%20between%20two%20points%20site%3astackoverflow.com&meta=).